# How to collect and display visit statistics for a Views page?

Tags: views, nodes, google-analytics

I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction for the following:

I'd like to collect and display statistics for a [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) page.

I wonder what's the best approach for collecting basic 'hit' statistics for a views page (essentially a visitor counter for that view). The view uses contextual filtering (i.e. nid) to render content. Ideally, each path (i.e. viewpath/12, where 12 is the nid) has separate statistics.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Here are some reports you get from it:

> - View pages that have recently been visited.
> - View pages that have been hit frequently.
> - View pages count per month, day of month, day of week, hour.
> - ...

Especially these reports should be what you're looking for (it includes hits for paths corresponding to a view):

- [Top pages](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/top_pages.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Title, Path and nr of Hits).
- [Recent hits](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/reports/recent_hits.inc?h=7.x-2.x) (table with columns Date of visit, Title, Path and User ID of the visitor).

Checkout the above (source) links to get an idea of which data are available.

Extra reporting features can be enabled via these sub-modules:

- The **Visitors GeoIP** module, to also report about countries and cities.
- The **Visitors Browscap** module, providing statistics on visiting browsers.

The demo site contains [some sample reports (charts)](http://drupal.placeto.be/visitors) available to anonymous users also. This demo site also shows some additional blocks with reports also created by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module module.

You may also want to look at the [visitors_schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/visitors/tree/visitors.install?h=7.x-2.x#n37) to get an idea of the data that actually get logged (recorded) by this module.

In case it's not a perfect fit, it's probably a very good starting point for some custom reporting. Either via a custom module that would simply have to query the data maintained by the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module. Or via a straight forward custom report created with the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) module,
and co-maintainer of the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module.

Comment: Thanks Pierre, I was unaware of the Visitors module - it looks really promising and should cover my requirements. I'll give it a shot soon and report back.

Comment: @ymdahi Merci for the (late) accept!